@WithMockUser not working, still getting 401
This is my spring test, I am testing a secured endpoint that creates recipes for a given user.
What is the proper way to test a secured endpoint?
Isn't the @WithMockUser annotation enough?
I am still getting 401.
package com.joaogoncalves.recipes.controller;

import com.joaogoncalves.recipes.model.RecipeCreate;
import com.joaogoncalves.testcontainers.EnableTestContainers;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;

import java.util.List;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableTestContainers
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class RecipeControllerIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + port;
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @WithMockUser
    public void testRecipeCreateOk() {
        final RecipeCreate recipeCreate = new RecipeCreate(
                "tomato soup",
                "tomato soup with anchovies",
                List.of("tomato", "water", "anchovies"),
                List.of("peel the tomatoes", "add water", "boil for 30 minutes", "add the anchovies"),
                "soup"
        );
        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(recipeCreate)
                .when()
                .post("/api/recipe/new")
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
}

This is my SecurityFilterChain, which is inside a SecurityConfig class. I'm requesting authentication with USER role for all endpoints but /api/register.
package com.joaogoncalves.recipes.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

I tried a different approach with @WithUserDetails also without success.
package com.joaogoncalves.recipes.controller;

import com.joaogoncalves.recipes.model.RecipeCreate;
import com.joaogoncalves.recipes.model.UserCreate;
import com.joaogoncalves.recipes.service.UserService;
import com.joaogoncalves.testcontainers.EnableTestContainers;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;

import java.util.List;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableTestContainers
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class RecipeControllerIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + port;
        userService.create(new UserCreate("chef@chef.com", "chefpassword"));
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @WithUserDetails(value = "chef@chef.com", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "userService")
    public void testRecipeCreateOk() {
        final RecipeCreate recipeCreate = new RecipeCreate(
                "tomato soup",
                "tomato soup with anchovies",
                List.of("tomato", "water", "anchovies"),
                List.of("peel the tomatoes", "add water", "boil for 30 minutes", "add the anchovies"),
                "soup"
        );
        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(recipeCreate)
                .when()
                .post("/api/recipe/new")
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
}

Thanks in advance.

Could you show us your security filter chain configuration?

Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails

you cant use withmockuser when you are running your tests in a standalone application, its supposed to be used during mock testing, when your tests build a dummy ApplicationContext, and the test can populate the SecurityContext in the mock. Its basically used for testing method security

I think you need a WebApplicationContext when using @WithMockUser for dummy user in your test. However RestAssured is not working with Spring Application Context. When you want to test endpoint with RestAssured, you need to use RestAssuredMockMvc class.

How to pass Spring SecurityContext to RestAssured

Dependency is this.
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc'

I cannot perfectly reproduce your test code, but I could make three test cases for same endpoint.

Using MockMVC - I made this because I want double check it is working in MockMvc.
Using RestAssured - This is your case.
Using RestAssuredMockMvc - This is what you want I think.

SecurityConfig
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

Test codes
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import java.util.List;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

record RecipeCreate(
        String name,
        String details,
        List<String> ingredient,
        List<String> steps,
        String type
) {
}

@RestController
class RecipeController {

    @PostMapping("/api/recipe/new")
    public String createRecipe(@RequestBody RecipeCreate recipeCreate) {
        System.out.println(recipeCreate);
        return "ok";
    }
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RecipeControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext applicationContext;
    MockMvc sut;
    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + port;
        sut = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(applicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void testRecipeCreateOk_success() throws Exception {

        final RecipeCreate recipeCreate = new RecipeCreate(
                "tomato soup",
                "tomato soup with anchovies",
                List.of("tomato", "water", "anchovies"),
                List.of("peel the tomatoes", "add water", "boil for 30 minutes", "add the anchovies"),
                "soup"
        );


        sut.perform(
                post("/api/recipe/new")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(recipeCreate))
        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void testRecipeCreateOk_failure() {

        final RecipeCreate recipeCreate = new RecipeCreate(
                "tomato soup",
                "tomato soup with anchovies",
                List.of("tomato", "water", "anchovies"),
                List.of("peel the tomatoes", "add water", "boil for 30 minutes", "add the anchovies"),
                "soup"
        );


        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(recipeCreate)
                .when()
                .post("/api/recipe/new")
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void testRecipeCreateOk_successWithRestAssured() {

        final RecipeCreate recipeCreate = new RecipeCreate(
                "tomato soup",
                "tomato soup with anchovies",
                List.of("tomato", "water", "anchovies"),
                List.of("peel the tomatoes", "add water", "boil for 30 minutes", "add the anchovies"),
                "soup"
        );


        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(recipeCreate)
                .when()
                .post("/api/recipe/new")
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        RestAssuredMockMvc.reset();
    }
}


This way totally beats the purpose of using @SpringBootTest and its automatic way of setting up MockMvc and just adds overhead and unneeded complexity.

@M.Deinum Do you mean @Import?

When using SpringBootTest annotation, I think Spring application context is set up automatically, but yesterday I figured out that security filter chain is not used own one without Import annotation.

No how you setup mockmvc. That is totally not needed and still wouldn't work as @WithMockUser and friends only work with a mocked context, here a real application is started and the mocked context isn't used so even if you setup it up like this it wouldn't yield any result.

So how do I setup mockmvc? Can you give me an example?
Here is the repository what I did. I want to know the best practice mockmvc context setup with spring security. If you have a time, fork and PR please.
https://github.com/Junhyunny/spring-security-test

Just use @AutoConfigureMockMvc nothing more nothing less. But that won't do anything withy your current setup as the @SpringBootTest uses a real server due to RANDOM_PORT and not the mocked servlet environment.

Okay, I see. I just added MockMvc in the answer because I wanted to check MockMvc is working or not in the same environment. @WithMockUser is working with that environment actually. If you change the roles of @WithMockUser or make comment out that line then test fails because I use the real security filter chain which is set up by the developer in the test environment. You have already known @WithMockUser's default role is USER so test is succeeded with @WithMockUser. If you want to check then see my repo.

@AutoConfigureMockMvc does exactly the same. If you need the import there is something strange going on in your configuration (like not being covered by the component scan etc. ). This makes "it work" however you shouldn't be using MockMvc here at all as it is a full blown integration test. So this mixing is a bad thing. Either use a proper mocked environment with the default for @SpringBootTest or send the credentials with the request as basic-auth is enabled.

That's true. I made a mistake that I made SecurityConfig in the wrong package not inside the base package. I edited the answer to remove something wrong information.
